# The definition of Riemann to complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

According to a definition I [saw](https://books.google.com/books?id=jWxDAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA21&lpg=PA21&dq=A%20complex%20variable%20w%20is%20said%20to%20be%20a%20function%20of%20another%20complex%20variable%20z,%20if%20w%20varies%20with%20z%20in%20such%20a%20way%20that%20the%20value%20of%20the%20derivative%20~~%20is%20independent%20of%20the%20value%20of%20the%20differential%20dz.&source=bl&ots=16q6-fI4XM&sig=ACfU3U2bJ6GQVVhD4irQBXXbicB9NXvmdQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQ_POv1r_oAhXDjqQKHf3pAU0Q6AEwAHoECA0QKA#v=onepage&q=A%20complex%20variable%20w%20is%20said%20to%20be%20a%20function%20of%20another%20complex%20variable%20z%2C%20if%20w%20varies%20with%20z%20in%20such%20a%20way%20that%20the%20value%20of%20the%20derivative%20~~%20is%20independent%20of%20the%20value%20of%20the%20differential%20dz.&f=false):

> A complex variable $w$ is said to be a function of another complex variable $z$, if $w$ varies with $z$ in such a way that the value of the derivative $\frac{dw}{dz}$ is independent of the value of the differential $d$z.

I failed to grasp this definition or to see the contrast between real function (or variable) and complex variable. help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition you've quoted is a historical one from Riemann and uses the term "function" (and "$dz$") in a nonstandard way. The next sentence in your book gives the equivalent modern definition of [differentiability of a complex function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#Differentiability_in_complex_analysis).

Comment: thank you. I wonder where can I read about the terminology Riemann was using?

Comment: I think he just means that the ratio "change in w"/"change in z", as both approach 0, does not depend on the *direction* of the "change in z".

Answer (score 0):

The real definition is: The derivative of $f$ at $z$ is defined as:

$\begin{align*}
    f'(z)
      &= \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{f(z + h) - f(z)}{h}
\end{align*}$

If the limit doesn't exist, the derivative isn't defined. Just like the case of the real derivative.

Note that $z = x + y i$, you have to consider *both* components of $z$ when computing limits. The imagery of "$x$ approaches $a$" here needs to consider the path too.